# Why do people downvote so much here?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm not sure if it's just me, but people seem to downvote both questions and answers more frequently here than on any other (popular) SE site like StackOverflow for example.

Is it *just me* or am I right? If so, what's the reason?

Comment: Please provide examples of where you are noticing this.  Without that, there's no evidence to support your claim.

Comment: People *vote* here more. Our questions have many more upvotes as well as downvotes.

Comment: @lesderid This is meta; downvotes mean they don't agree with your premise, ie. That we downvote more than most sites.  I mean, you had no downvotes at all until you posted this.  Heck, you STILL don't have any on the main site.  I'd really recommend you back up your claims with a link or two.

Comment: @lesderid I'm afraid your question title *begs* for downvotes. You can edit it if it really bothers you

Comment: The temptation was just too much for most of us to resist

Comment: This site does seem to have a less *mature* userbase...

Comment: @lesderid We're asking for *proof*.  As far as we can tell, you joined today, asked a single question, then made this meta post.  You have provided nothing in the way of evidence that, perhaps, you might have a point.  Also, gaming is supposed to be *fun*.  We take that to heart here.  Everybody's face is mature!

Comment: And yet people still don't downvote enough http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one

Comment: On second thoughts, this is probably just [fbueckert](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/20456/fbueckert)'s fault.

Comment: FWIW, I have made about 1400 upvotes and 600 downvotes on Arqade.  On SO, I have made about 2200 upvotes and 1800 downvotes.

Comment: its funny that this question has so many downvotes. They should count as upvotes for the OP just to add to the hilarity, plus its a decent question even if its assumption is wrong.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262018/how-to-control-playstation-3-without-a-controller-and-with-a-pc/262124#262124

is one example I can think of, it was a perfectly valid question. yet it got downvoted.

Comment: @Frank i think they mean on gaming, not meta

Comment: @TheGeorgeL That is what I was referring to, as well

Answer (score 21):

Here's some actual data for you.

On Gaming.SE, the average Question score is **5.54**:

http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/95438/average-question-score

[image]

On SO, it's **1.57**:

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/95438/average-question-score

[image]

So we *do* vote a hell of a lot more here, and I'd give this as evidence that we downvote more, but also upvote more.

Comment: I'd like to point out that SO has 4.1 million questions, while Arqade only has 26 thousand.

Comment: @tiddy SO has more downvotes, but we have more downvotes per question

Comment: @fredley "Vote Down requires 125 reputation" :(

Comment: @tiddy Exactly this. Comparing a sample pool of 26,000 versus 4,100,000 is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: @Kotsu This comparison was put forth in the question.

Comment: using sample sets of even size, Arqade downvote more than SO.

Comment: @pixel Source data?

Comment: @fredley random assumption, a wild guess, prayer in the wind, cake

Comment: @fredley What I was saying, is you need postype.id in (1,2) - otherwise you're just looking at questions, rather than both questions and answers (and there are a lot more upvotes on SO's answers in comparison to their questions), doesn't really change their score much but it does bring ours down slightly.

Comment: As long as we're complaining about data set size, Arqade has 24k questions to UX's 6k while Arqade has 5 average score to UX's 3. It's occasionally been said we downvote *too little* on UX too, so I think "Arqade is vote happy" is a pretty fair assessment.

Comment: @lesderid Downvoting requires reputation so that people can't just roll in from Teh Internets and tell the existing, reputation-having community how things should work while being uninformed about how things might have or have not worked already. 125 rep is the minimum test that a user has been around long enough to maybe understand the particular factors that influence a site's culture and policies.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i.e., asking 5 average questions.

Comment: @fredley Yep, IME there are those who just "get" the site enough, and they ask average questions. Those who don't quite get it tend to not ask well-voted questions, and they have to work at figuring out how this place works.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I obviously know that, I was just joking about that reputation thingy.

Comment: @lesderid Sorry! It's really, really hard to read deadpan humour in text. As a fond deadpanner I often fall afoul of that from the other direction.

Comment: Downvotes == Reversal, woo!

Answer (score 14):

Gaming, as an expert topic on a Q&A site, has some extra difficulties that a lot of other topics don't have. It's very easy for sites about Gaming to devolve into trolling, flame wars, opinion pieces, rants, etc.

As such, we have developed one of the strictest communities and strictest sets of guidelines for what belongs here. We downvote things that don't belong to get the point across that no, we don't accept content like that.

Do we downvote more than other sites? I have no idea. Are we justified in downvoting bad content? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I've noticed Workplace has collectively developed a quick downvote reflex as well for similar reasons, which I'm quite proud to see.

Answer (score 2):

One point that has been touched upon already is the user base/question count - sites like Stack Overflow have a larger userbase and therefore on average, more questions per minute.

**Example:**

Imagine that on average, votes (up or down) were 20% of views. *(Grossly exaggerated)*

- A question with 100 views will have 20 votes.
- A question with 10 views will have 2 votes

What this means on Stack Overflow is that a single question won't remain on people's radars for very long, it quickly gets pushed out of the top 50 by other questions.

Whereas here on Arqade (or any of the smaller sites for that matter), a question might stay on the front page (or the newest questions tab) for **days**.

This results in more people seeing the question in general, and therefore there will be more down/up votes.

Comment: I wanted to spew a lot of stats, but one thing in particular is pageviews/day per registered user.  On Arqade, it's somewhere around 5.  The next closest I think is Stack Overflow at about 3, with only a few others on the network near there.  Most are 1-2 pageviews/day per registerd user, or lower.